# Ford Figo has difficulty starting

Tags: manual-transmission

My 2013 Ford Figo has a starting problem. I have taken it to a local ford dealer several times but every time after allegedly fixing it, the problem will resurface.

I mostly encounter the problem when the car parked in the sun for too long.

It doesn't struggle starting in the morning or in cooler conditions.

Comment: Your question is a little bit vague. Could you provide some background on what the dealerships thought the problem was and what they looked at? That could help narrow it down.

Comment: Basic info such as petrol or diesel would be a good start... As it was available with either a 1.2 duratec petrol or 1.4 duratorq diesel and based on the common or garden Ford Fiesta... Vapour lock in the fuel system could be a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

A very wild theory... Could it be some kind of temperature sensor failing? A cold engine is started differently from a hot engine. If the engine control unit (ECU) thinks that the engine is cold where it's in reality hot, it may fail to start the engine. Usually these kinds of problems appear when re-start is attempted directly after a long drive. Now, could long parking in the sun produce such temperatures? Perhaps.

I don't think you'll get a better answer with the limited information you provided.

The transmission type (manual / automatic) has no effect on starting problems.